# How to configure auto indentation on VSCode to not break line in the middle of the HTML text?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting

I'm using the VSCode auto-indentation(Alt+ Shift+ f). The VSCode is breaking the line in the middle of the text, example, look the content indentation of tag `<b></b>`:

```
<div>
    <div class="panel vpush-1">
        <b>WBTS-2297_RNC-50_WSET-SQM3G_PLMN-PLMN: Voice Radio Bearers Downlink BLER is too
            high</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I configure to not break line in the middle of the text or configure VSCode to just increase the number of character to not happen this any more?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

You can add `"html.format.wrapLineLength": 0` in settings.json.

alternatively you can go to settings:

```
Settings -> Extensions -> HTML:
Format: Wrap Line Length
Maximum amount of characters per line (0 = disable).
0
```